# What angle halves the volume of a hemisphere?

Tags: geometry

Similar to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3366064/how-deep-is-the-liquid-in-a-half-full-hemisphere), when needing to measure out 1/2 tablespoon, I use my hemispherical tablespoon, but I hold mine at an angle and fill to the lowest edge. At what angle should I tilt so that my tablespoon is only half full?

Convention note: 0 degrees is level where the tablespoon holds a full tablespoon. 90 degrees would be holding the tablespoon sideways where it holds no liquid. In practice I usually hold at a little less than 45 degree angle, i.e. more level than tipped.

[image]

Comment: Mark the centre of the hemisphere. The liquid surface should be $\approx (1- 65\%)$, or exactly $2\cos(4\pi/9)$, of the radius from the centre (result from [a comment in the linked question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3366064/89922#comment6927081_3366064)). Then $\sin\theta =2\cos(4\pi/9) \approx 1-65\%$.

Comment: [Quick beginner guide for asking a well-received question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/35391/quick-beginner-guide-for-asking-a-well-received-question) + please [avoid "no clue" questions](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/27933#27933).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the radius of the hemisphere is $R$ then the volume of the tilted spoon is

$ V = \pi ( \dfrac{2}{3} R^3 - a R^2 + \dfrac{1}{3} a^3 ) $

where $a = R \sin \theta $

This comes from the formula for the volume of a spherical cap of height $h$ in a sphere of radius $R$.  The formula is listed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_cap).  What it says there is that the volume is given by

$ V = \dfrac{\pi h^2}{3} ( 3 R - h) $

In our problem, $h = R - a $.  Therefore,

$ V = \dfrac{\pi (R - a)^2}{3} (2 R + a ) = \dfrac{1}{3} \pi ( R^2 - 2 a R + a^2 )(2 R + a) $

And this gives the formula above.

Now, we want to solve

$  \dfrac{\pi R^3}{3} = \pi ( \dfrac{2}{3} R^3 - a R^2 + \dfrac{1}{3} a^3 ) $

Take $R = 1 $, then

$ \dfrac{1}{3} a^3 - a + \dfrac{1}{3} = 0 $

i.e.

$ a^3 - 3 a + 1 = 0 $

Solving the general cubic equation is addressed [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation).

Here, our cubic equation is of the form

$t^3 + p t + q = 0 $

It is explained [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_equation#Depressed_cubic) how a trigonometric solution is obtained for this cubic equation.  If $ 4 p^3 + 27 q^2 \lt 0 $ then
there will be three solutions given by

$ t_k = 2 \sqrt{ -\dfrac{p}{3}} \cos \left( \dfrac{1}{3} \cos^{-1} \left( \dfrac{3 q }{2 p} \sqrt{ \dfrac{-3}{p}} \right) - \dfrac{2 \pi k }{3 } \right) \hspace{10pt} \text{ for } k = 0, 1, 2 $

This formula is due to the French mathematician [François Viète](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois_Vi%C3%A8te).

Substituting $ p = -3 , q = 1 $ we first verify that there is indeed three real roots, because $4p^3 + 27 q^2 \lt 0 $.  Then we have

$ t_k = 2 \cos \left( \dfrac{1}{3} \cos^{-1} \left( -\dfrac{1 }{2 }  \right) - \dfrac{2 \pi k }{3 } \right) \hspace{10pt} \text{ for } k = 0, 1, 2 $

This simplifies further to

$ t_k = 2 \cos \left( \dfrac{2 \pi}{9} - \dfrac{2 \pi k }{3 } \right) \hspace{10pt} \text{ for } k = 0, 1, 2 $

So the three roots are

$t_1 = 2 \cos \left( \dfrac{2 \pi}{9} \right) = 1.53208888$

$t_2 = 2 \cos \left( \dfrac{4 \pi}{9} \right) = 0.3472963 $

$ t_3 = 2 \cos \left( \dfrac{ 10 \pi }{9 }\right) = -1.87938524 $

The only valid solution is $t_2$.  Hence, we have

$ a = \sin \theta = 2 \cos \left( \dfrac{4 \pi}{9} \right) $

From which

$ \theta = \sin^{-1} \left( 2 \cos \left( \dfrac{4 \pi}{9} \right) \right) = \sin^{-1}(0.3472963) = \boxed{20.322^\circ}$

Comment: Where does the initial volume formula come from?

Comment: @Aeryk Please check my updated solution.